# How to parse a json retrieved from a URL in windows store apps?

Tags: json, windows-store-apps

Am trying to call a url, grab the json which is returned and parse it to extract info.

Here is my code in C# windows store app.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var uri = new Uri("http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo");
string jsonstring = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
var parsedResponse = JsonArray.Parse(jsonstring);
```

At this line am getting the below error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> WinRT information: Invalid character at position 0.
>
> Additional information: Invalid JSON string.

Comment: Could you share a sample JSON response?

Answer (score 1):

If you try the Json validator at http://jsonlint.com/ the JSON seems to be valid you should try JSON .NET is the most common used library to work with JSON in .NET http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx.

Also I see that you are calling `JsonArray.Parse` I'm not sue but It makes me think that it is expecting an array `[]` but  the response is an object `{}`. If there is a method `JsonObject.Parse` it may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the String returned is a JSON Object and not an Array. try this

```
 var parsedResponse = JsonObject.Parse(jsonstring);
```